# Is it safe to use vector push_back in an OpenMP parallel region?

Tags: c++, openmp

I know I am not supposed to throw any uncaught exceptions from inside an openmp parallel region.  Therefore I do not think the following loops are safe because the push_back function of vector could cause a reallocation of memory which could potentially throw an exception.

I looked up the documentation and it says that `If a reallocation happens, the strong guarantee is also given if the type of the elements is either copyable or no-throw moveable.`

So is my code here safe?  Star is a basic data struct containing floats.

```
        std::vector<Star> stars;

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(size_t i = 1; i < (gimg.height() - 1) * 2; i++)
        {
            float i_ = i / 2.0f;

            for(float j = 1; j < gimg.width() - 1; j += 0.5f)
            {
                //a b c
                //d e f
                //g h k

                quantum_t e = gimg.bilinear(j, i_);

                quantum_t a = gimg.bilinear(j - 1, i_ - 1);
                if(a >= e) continue;

                quantum_t b = gimg.bilinear(j, i_ - 1);
                if(b >= e) continue;

                quantum_t c = gimg.bilinear(j + 1, i_ + 1);
                if(c >= e) continue;

                quantum_t d = gimg.bilinear(j - 1, i_);
                if(d >= e) continue;

                quantum_t f = gimg.bilinear(j + 1, i_);
                if(f >= e) continue;

                quantum_t g = gimg.bilinear(j - 1, i_ + 1);
                if(g >= e) continue;

                quantum_t h = gimg.bilinear(j, i_ + 1); 
                if(h >= e) continue;

                quantum_t k = gimg.bilinear(j + 1, i_ + 1);
                if(k >= e) continue;

                bool ismax = d >= a && d >= g && h >= g && h >= k && f >= k && f >= c && b >= c && b >= a;

                if(ismax)
                {
                    Star s;
                    s.brightness = e;
                    s.location = Point<float>(j, i_);

                    #pragma omp critical
                    stars.push_back(s);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If throwing uncaught exceptions is bad, why not put the `push_back` in a `try-catch`?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenMP standard says, near the end of [section 2.7.1](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf#G4.996952):

> A throw executed inside a loop region must cause execution to resume
>   within the same iteration of the loop region, and the same thread that
>   threw the exception must catch it.

So enclosing your `push_back()` with a `try`-`catch` construct, itself within the `critical` region should make you code safe.